# How to avoid 'cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable' of a closure?

Tags: design-patterns, rust

Here is my sample code, and the compiler error beneath.

```rust
struct A {
    value: i32,
    closure: Box<dyn Fn(&mut Self) -> ()>,
}

impl A {
    fn call_closure(&mut self) -> () {
        (self.closure)(self)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let _foo = A {
        value: 0,
        closure: Box::new(move |a: &mut A| {
            a.value = 10;
        }),
    };
}
```

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
 --> src/main.rs:8:9
  |
8 |         (self.closure)(self)
  |         --------------^^^^^^
  |         |
  |         mutable borrow occurs here
  |         immutable borrow occurs here
  |         immutable borrow later used by call
```

I understand why the compiler gives this error, but I'm hoping for code like this that allows a closure as field to modify fields of the structure.

Are there any good ideas or designs? What is the idiomatic way here?

Comment: *that allows a closure [...] to modify fields of the structure* — and what happens if the closure attempts to modify the closure itself (`a.closure = ...`)?

Comment: Therefore, in order to prevent that closure attempts to modify the closure itself, such code is prohibited in Rust?

Comment: That's correct. The primary refactoring is to [split up your code into multiple parts](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=267b2972bae7f784152a90d40a30f435).

Comment: OK! Thank you very much for fast answer!
I'm sorry for my bad English. I will rethink about my program design.

Comment: No need to apologize for your English — you communicated your point just fine! I just tidy up almost every question / answer to help make [tag:rust] as good as possible.